# How to set Table Row height and the Cell Options as Fit Text with Content Control in word Addin | Officejs

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-addins, office-js-helpers

I have existing word plugin in C# and I'm converting it to Office.js. My requirement is to Add Table in word with 1 row and 1 column. The Cell text would be Content Control of table and text should fit to entire row and also Specify the Row height as mentioned in below Expected results snapshots.
Below is my code in react.
[Code in react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iIzr.png)

**Actual Result:**(output of the new implementation i.e. Office.js)
[Actual Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mDT1.png)

**Expected Result:**(Existing Plugin result i.e. C#)
[Exptected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL2Y6.png)

Please guide/provide me sample code to achieve this in Office.js

Answer (score 0):

Try using [TableRow.preferredHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.tablerow?view=office-js#preferredheight) to set the height and set [TableCell.horizontalAlighnment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.tablecell?view=office-js#horizontalalignment) to `Justified` to get the contents to fill the cell.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. 1st one is worked i.e. **preferredHieght** but the 2'nd one  Alignment issue didn't work. As you suggested, i have tried as follows `context.document.body.tables.getFirst().rows.getFirst().cells.getFirst().horizontalAlignment = "Justified"` but didn't work. is there any other way to achieve the **Fit Text** option enabling for table Cell ?